# Relating two Drupal 7 views filters

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-exposed-filter

Say there are two Drupal 7 views exposed filters, one called People, another one called City. If I select one city from the City filter, then the people in the People filter should only contain people who live in the selected city.

This is very simple in SQL:

```
select * 
from People
left join City
on People.city_id = City.id
where City.id=xxx;
```

How can I do this with exposed filters in Drupal 7 views?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) can do the trick. You can specify fields dependency.